# Why does bit-wise negate operator "~" cast to int? (conversion to ‘unsigned char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value)

Tags: c++, type-conversion, bit-manipulation, compiler-warnings

GCC 4.9.1 reports "warning: conversion to ‘unsigned char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]" with the following code

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main( int , char*[] ) {
  unsigned char *dest = new unsigned char[16];
  const unsigned char *src = new unsigned char[16];
  for( size_t i = 0; i != 16; ++i) {
    dest[i] = ~(src[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Obviously, both `src` and `dest` are both pointers to an array of `unsigned char` and I only want the latter to be the bit-wise negation of the former. For some strange reason the `~` operator seems to return an `int` and thus triggering the warning. Why? Is this intended behaviour?

Of course, I know I could use a `static_cast<unsigned char>()` to prevent the warning, but I feel that something else is wrong and the warning should not be there in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the literal answer is because the Standard says so. From [expr.unary.op]:

> The operand of `~` shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type; the result is the one’s complement of its operand. Integral promotions are performed. **The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.**

which, according to [conv.prom] is:

> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t` whose integer conversion
>   rank (4.13) is less than the rank of `int` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned int`.

And `int` has higher rank than `unsigned char`. So yes, it's intended behavior, and an explicit `static_cast` squelches the warning.

Answer (score 0):

all operands in expressions are promoted to at least `int`s, because `int` should represent 'natural' integral type for given architecture.

So this warning is proper - type on right side of assignment will be `int` (for some people it might indicate place for optimization*), `static_cast` is a good solution (I would add mask for `0xFF` to it, just to be sure and properly state my intent).

*) for example: one could negate 4 bytes at once, making better use of CPU. Some compilers might do it by them selfs.